# Why are SQLite transactions bound to harddisk rotation?

Tags: sqlite, transactions

There's [a following statement in SQLite FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q19):

> A transaction normally requires two complete rotations of the disk platter, which on a 7200RPM disk drive limits you to about 60 transactions per second.

As I know there's a cache on the harddisk and there might be also an extra cache in the disk driver that abstract the operation that is perceived by the software from the actual operation against the disk platter.

Then why and how exactly are transactions so strictly bound to disk platter rotation?

Answer (score 2):

From [Atomic Commit In SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/atomiccommit.html)

> ### 2.0 Hardware Assumptions
>
> SQLite assumes that the operating
>   system will buffer writes and that a
>   write request will return before data
>   has actually been stored in the mass
>   storage device. SQLite further assumes
>   that write operations will be
>   reordered by the operating system. **For
>   this reason, SQLite does a "flush" or
>   "fsync" operation at key points.
>   SQLite assumes that the flush or fsync
>   will not return until all pending
>   write operations for the file that is
>   being flushed have completed.** We are
>   told that the flush and fsync
>   primitives are broken on some versions
>   of Windows and Linux. This is
>   unfortunate. It opens SQLite up to the
>   possibility of database corruption
>   following a power loss in the middle
>   of a commit. However, there is nothing
>   that SQLite can do to test for or
>   remedy the situation. SQLite assumes
>   that the operating system that it is
>   running on works as advertised. If
>   that is not quite the case, well then
>   hopefully you will not lose power too
>   often.

Answer (score 1):

Because it ensures data integrity by making sure the data is actually written on to the disk rather than held in memory. Thus if the power goes off or something, the database is not corrupted.

This video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f428dSRkTs4 talks about reasons why (e.g. because SQLite is actually used in a lot of embedded devices where the power might well suddenly go off.)

Comment: Why is there a guarantee that the disk controller will actuall perform the write?

Comment: But that's the key problem. If the disk controller can delay the actual write for unknown period there's no point in bounding to rotation - the program can skip whatever number of rotations, yet no write to the platter will occur.

Comment: @Nick D: I guess this explains a lot and should go as an answer, not comment.

Comment: Disk manufacturers aren't entirely stupid, and do not delay writes needlessly. See for more details http://serverfault.com/questions/15404/sata-disks-that-handle-write-caching-properly